# Data base foreign keys don't connect to the primary key

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble getting the information from foreign keys in my Doctor's table DepartmentID and SID (BOTH FOREIGN KEYS) and for admissions tables, I can't get the info from TID (FK) which is PK for the treatment table. I already input data to my data base but for some reason the FK aren't connecting to their respective PK tables. What can I change to solve this and any othher feedback to improve my script. I've attached both tables for reference.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Patient (
    PID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    PFname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PLname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    DOB DATE NOT NULL,
    PNumber VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    PEmail VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    )
    ;
    
CREATE TABLE Doctor (
    DID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    DFname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    DLname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    )
    ;
    
CREATE TABLE Department (
    DepartmentID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    DepartmentName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Buildingname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FloorNum INT NOT NULL,
    Head_DocID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (Head_DocID) REFERENCES Doctor(DID)
    )
    ;

CREATE TABLE Admissions (
    AID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Admission_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Release_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    DID INT,
    PID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (DID) REFERENCES Doctor(DID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PID) REFERENCES Patient(PID)
    )
    ;
        
CREATE TABLE Treatment (
    TID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    TDate DATE NOT NULL,
    TDescription VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    DID INT,
    AID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (DID) REFERENCES Doctor(DID),
    FOREIGN KEY (AID) REFERENCES Admissions(AID)
    )
    ;
    
CREATE TABLE Emer_contact (
    ECID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ECFname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ECLname VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL,
    ECPnumber VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    ECemail VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Relationship VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    )
    ;
    
CREATE TABLE doc_specialty (
    SID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    DID INT NOT NULL,
    Specialty VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (DID) REFERENCES Doctor(DID)
    )
    ;

CREATE TABLE Specialty_Info (
    SIID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    DID INT,
    SID INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY (DID) REFERENCES Doctor(DID),
    FOREIGN KEY (SID) REFERENCES Doc_Specialty(SID) 
)
;

CREATE TABLE Treatment_Info (
    TIID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    AID INT,
    TID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (AID) REFERENCES Admissions(AID),
    FOREIGN KEY (TID) REFERENCES Treatment(TID)
)
;

ALTER TABLE Doctor
ADD COLUMN DepartmentID INT;

ALTER TABLE Doctor 
ADD CONSTRAINT DepartmentID
FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentID)
REFERENCES Department(DepartmentID)
;

ALTER TABLE Doctor
ADD COLUMN SID INT;

ALTER TABLE Doctor 
ADD CONSTRAINT SID
FOREIGN KEY (SID)
REFERENCES Doc_Specialty(SID)
;

ALTER TABLE Admissions
ADD COLUMN ECID INT;

ALTER TABLE Admissions 
ADD CONSTRAINT ECID
FOREIGN KEY (ECID)
REFERENCES Emer_Contact(ECID)
;

ALTER TABLE Admissions
ADD COLUMN TID INT;

ALTER TABLE Admissions
ADD CONSTRAINT TID
FOREIGN KEY (TID)
REFERENCES Treatment(TID)
;
```

[Admission table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvKVZ.png)
[Doctor table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mQI9.png)

Comment: Your scheme is correct. https://dbfiddle.uk/N_HjBMr0 Provide more detailed data about your issue, for example, provide code which fails or returns incorrect output.

Comment: I posted 2 pictures with both tables and it doesn’t show the data for those fields. Everything else shows but not the data for the FK

Comment: Pictures are not useful. Post sample data as INSERT INTO, your query which produces incorrect result and desired output / final data state. According to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: FKs do not push or pull values..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.